# Installing Memcached on existing App servers

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached

We're analyzing on improving the performance by implementing Memcached to our ASP.Net application.
We have several webservers , 12 app server cluster with a load balancer and DB tier. To implement the Memcached, do we need another tier of servers (caching tier) or can we install Memcached on the existing App servers. What are the implications ? If we install on existing App servers, ideally how many should act as Memcached servers and how many as clients. Please throw some light.
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How large is the data set to cache?

Comment: It will be around 500MB of space.

Comment: Put memcache on the app server, your data set it tiny. Use a client that supports consistent hashing, split data set across 5 servers, 100Mb each.

Comment: Thanks for your response raffian